# Redirect/dispatch to the origin jsp after using a Translation Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect, translation, forward

I'm implementing a function to translate all my JSP pages automatically in French or English. The user will have two buttons at every moment in the navigation to change the language. I used a servlet to deal with this language change but I don't know how to automatically redirect to the right JSP page each time this servlet is called. It's probably trivial but I cannot figure out how to do it so please help me...

I created a JSP file only to store a header which is going to be used in almost all my other JSPs to offer translation services to the users :

In header.jsp :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<div id="settings">
        <p><fmt:message key="connection"/><c:out value=" ${sessionScope.firstname} ${sessionScope.name}"></c:out> <a href="../../disconnect"><fmt:message key = "disconnect"/></a></p>
        <p id="translateText"><fmt:message key="translation"/> :
            <a href="../../language?lang=fr" onclick=""><img src="../css/images/icone_fr.gif" alt="Français"></a>
            <a href="../../language?lang=en" onclick=""><img src="../css/images/icone_en.gif" alt="English"></a>   
        </p>
</div>

</html>
```

Then I include this jsp in all other JSP files which use these translation functions (e.g : example.jsp) :

example.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<!doctype html>
<html>


<!-- To initialize the language of the page -->
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty sessionScope.language ? sessionScope.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />


<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${language=='fr'}"><fmt:setBundle basename="translation/message_fr"/></c:when>
    <c:otherwise><fmt:setBundle basename="translation/message_en"/></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><fmt:message key="platform"/>!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="../text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">     </script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper"><!-- #wrapper -->


<%@ include file = "header.jsp" %>


<section id="main"><!-- #main content and sidebar area -->


        <section id="content"><!-- #content -->
            <h1><fmt:message key="newProject"/></h1>

                    <article>
                <p>blabla</p>
            </article>
                    </section>
  </section>
</div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on the link in "header.jsp" to change the language, the "Language" servlet is called and change the value of the language parameter in the sessionScope. This works properly but then, my servlet has to redirect (forward ?) the response to the origin JSP so that it is displayed again but in the proper language and that's what doesn't work for me.

My question is : How can I find or pass this JSP URL ? I tried request.getRequestURI() but it returns the Servlet URI and not the JSP sending the request.

Here is my servlet :

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Language
 */
@WebServlet("/language")
public class Language extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Language() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String lang = request.getParameter("lang");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("language", lang);
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());//give the servlet URI

    response.sendRedirect(//where ??????);

}

}
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use response.sendRedirect(.jsp?language='urlangaue').
so now the control goes to corrsponding jsp then you reterview the langaue by using request.parameter("langauge");